# Drag and Drop element to new area

Tags: .net, drag-and-drop, webforms

I'm working on a hobby project to strengthen my application development skills.  There's one particular piece that's giving me some trouble.

My project is a character generator for D&D.  Within one section I'm generating attribute scores.  I have a button which opens the 'generate' panel.  The generate panel has 6 attribute areas, which are programaticaly filled when they have met some requirements (choosing a method of generation from a list and clicking a button).

Each method of generation but one allows the user to assign the six scores to their six attributes.

I could easily have these be clickable buttons which would open a dialog (or modal, or similar) to choose where to assign the selected score, but that wouldn't teach me anything new.

What I would like to do, instead, is have the user drag-and-drop the attribute score (currently a text box in a panel) to the attribute they want to assign it to (currently each attribute is made from a text box, a label, and another textbox, I'd like the user to be able to drop the value into any of those three areas).

I'd also like to permit the user to drag-and-drop values between attribute scores, but that should follow fairly easily from the answer to the first part.

In short, **how do I make it possible for the user to drag the value of a control to another control within an application**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a considerable amount of searching, I found [this article](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2007/07/07/basic-drag-and-drop-in-winforms/) which describes the essentials of drag 'n drop in .NET webforms.

Copied below are the essentials:

In the MouseDown event for what you want to drag and drop, fire off the 'DoDragDrop' event, passing in the data you want to drop and a DragDropEffects value for what you want to achieve.

In the MouseEnter event of the objects which can accept drag&drops, run code like this:

```
if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Link) != 0

    && e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
```

e.AllowedEffect is bitwise, and can match against multiple effects.

Setting e.Effect says that the control can accept dropped data.  The effect you set to '.Effect' determines how the mouse will look.

Finally, on the 'DragDrop' event for whatever control accepts dropped data, you can access the moved data by using 'e.Data.GetData' - this will return a castable object.

This doesn't solve a few of my problems (notably, the mouse doesn't carry a 'shadow' of the data with it) but it's a good first step.